# Notepad++ - Aligning text vertically in multiple columns

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to align some lines in my code that has comments that could use with some alignment too. I used the notepad++ "[Code-Alignment](http://codealignment.com/)" plugin, and aligned the text below.

```python
class Constants(object):
    VAL_CONST = 5  # Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet = 213
    TEST_CONST = 0.2324  # Curabitur condimentum elementum = 32
    PARALLEL_CONST = 88  # Vivamus vehicula, mauris nec vehicula pulvinar, urna nibh mollis = 1342
    CURVE_SPATIAL_CONST = 0.000005892  # Donec sagittis in lacus = 0.55
```

I end up with the following:

```python
class Constants(object):
    VAL_CONST           = 5  # Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet = 213
    TEST_CONST          = 0.2324  # Curabitur condimentum elementum= 32
    PARALLEL_CONST      = 88  # Vivamus vehicula, mauris nec vehicula pulvinar, urna nibh mollis = 1342
    CURVE_SPATIAL_CONST = 0.000005892  # Donec sagittis in lacus %$ 0.55
```

However, I'd like to take this a step further. I'd like to "re-align" the code one more time, this time on the second set of "equals" signs. Preferably without going through the comments to change the second set of equals signs to be more unique.

End result of what I'd like:

```python
class Constants(object):
    VAL_CONST           = 5  # Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet                                        = 213
    TEST_CONST          = 0.2324  # Curabitur condimentum elementum                              = 32
    PARALLEL_CONST      = 88  # Vivamus vehicula, mauris nec vehicula pulvinar, urna nibh mollis = 1342
    CURVE_SPATIAL_CONST = 0.000005892  # Donec sagittis in lacus                                 = 0.55
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `Code alignment` [v3](http://cpmcgrath.com/blog/2012/02/code-alignment-3/) it's possible with the help of regular expressions.

First you have to align the first equal as you already did, with the ordinary way `Plugins` > `Code alignment` > `Align by equals`.

Then, go to `Plugins` > `Code alignment` > `Align by...` (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>) and write the following expression:

```
.+(?<x>=)
```

Don't forget to check the "Use regular expressions" option. This expression will align only the *last* equal, instead of the first.

These two steps will return the desired result:

```
class Constants(object):
    VAL_CONST           = 5  # Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet                                        = 213
    TEST_CONST          = 0.2324  # Curabitur condimentum elementum                              = 32
    PARALLEL_CONST      = 88  # Vivamus vehicula, mauris nec vehicula pulvinar, urna nibh mollis = 1342
    CURVE_SPATIAL_CONST = 0.000005892  # Donec sagittis in lacus                                 = 0.55
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I was trying to use the regular expression feature before I asked, but it didn't work. The bit I didn't understand was where to put the matching in terms of the named expression. I put the matching outside of it, rather than inside like you did.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using `Code Alignment` plugin for a while and found it to be very useful.
But it has two major issues from my point of view:

- it aligns only the first column given the delimiter character
- it uses .NET framework which makes it very slow at start-up and adds an extra dependency

I decided to create an alternative:

https://github.com/duzun/nppPyAlignColumn

This is a Python Script for Notepad++ Plugin named `Python Script`, that can be run from Menu.
It takes as input any string to be used as delimiter of columns and aligns all the columns in the selected lines.

Comment: Followed the install instructions, but I don't have any items under "scripts" in "Plugins->Python Script->Scripts"

Comment: I guess you have to restart NPP after you have copied `AlignColumns.py` to `C:\path\to\npp\plugins\Config\PythonScript\scripts\`.

Let me know how it works!

Comment: Did so, no dice :/ I know you wrote this ~ a year ago, and that npp has updated how plugins are handled in that time. Is it possible there's been a breaking change? (Edit: thanks for responding + supplying support on this :) )

Comment: I don't think there has been a breaking change in NPP, I'm still using this plugin everyday with NPP v6.8.

Comment: Does `Python Script` plugin work? 
Do you have python added to PATH?
Maybe your NPP settings are located in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++`. If so, try to copy `AlignColumns.py` to `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\Config\PythonScript\scripts`. This should be the place for user srcipts for `Python Script` plugin.
There is another path for scripts: `C:\path\to\npp\plugins\PythonScript\scripts\` - you could try this one.