# How do I get this result with excel, notepad++ or something else?

Tags: excel

i have opened same topic before; but since i have bad english it is closed by admin.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659829/how-can-i-write-this-list-easily

I need your help about word list. i have uploaded an image to explain my problem better.

[image: words]

i have thousands of lines like the left side and i want make them like right side.

as you see the words after dots are vertically aligned. the amount of the dots are different. how can i convert them like the right side?

word, notepad++, excel..?

thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know in detail, but a quick search of SO yielded using regex in Notepad++ to achieve something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481399/notepad-aligning-text-vertically-in-multiple-columns

Comment: If you'd ask this in CodeGolf, you would get absolultely weird methods to achieve that.

Comment: In Word replace all of the dots on each line with a single tab then create a tab stop with a dotted 'leader'. see [Show leaders or dots between tabs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-leaders-or-dots-between-tabs-CEA4B3DA-B614-4C50-9FED-15CBAAC5F164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in Word. Use Find and Replace to

- replace all occurrences of two dots with a tab character
- replace all occurrences of a tab character followed by a dot with a tab character
- replace all occurrences of two tab characters with one tab character
- repeat the last step until there are no more replacements reported and there is only one tab character on each line
- select all text and set the tab position far enough to the right. Alternatively use a Word style and apply it to all paragraphs in the text.
- format the Tab style to pad the spacing with dots.

[image]