# vertical align by key in notepad++ v7.6.2 (64-bit)

Tags: plugins, notepad++

i am using notepad++ (v7.6.2) (64-bit).
i would like to vertical align my selection according to a key i would choose.

Pretty much , the same as this discussion
[Notepad++ - Aligning text vertically in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481399/notepad-aligning-text-vertically-in-multiple-columns).
My problem, is that after installing the plugin `codealign`

- i don't find `codealign` under `Plugins > Code alignment` though it is present and installed under `plugin manager`
- the shortcut `ctrl+shift+=` does nothing.
- in the shortcut mapper, under the tab `plugin commands`, there's no
  `CodeAlignmentNpp.dll` as i would expect.

how to make it work?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code Alignment is not yet available for 64 bit notepad++.  You may want to use 32 bit notepad++ in case you want to use the features of Code Alignment.  For it to work on 64 bit more work is needed - https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment